# Is it possible to create a google app engine end point which can upload a photo in a blobstore?

Tags: google-app-engine, image-uploading, blobstore, google-cloud-endpoints

I would like to know if is it possible to upload a photo in a appengine blobstore by using an end point ?

If yes, please tell how or redirect to any available resource.

If not, can you please expose any simple alternative :

1. Using another library ?
2. Using a standard servlet with other libraries ?

Answer (score 4):

This post should be useful : [serving blobstore image through app-engine endpoints api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15562771/serving-blobstore-image-through-app-engine-endpoints-api?rq=1)

Please see another approach [The Photofeed sample Java app](https://developers.google.com/cloud/samples/photofeed/overview). There is also a [sample code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/solutions-photo-sharing-demo-java) . This app uses datastore to store photo metadata and comments about the photos and google cloud storage to store the actual photo.

Also check this post on [Image Upload in Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12381238/image-upload-in-google-app-engine) which mentions about storage using Blobstore

Comment: It seemes that the cloud storage using with the photofeed requiere to set billing information :(